# How do you get the app version in Tauri on the Rust side?

Tags: rust, tauri

The Tauri [docs](https://tauri.app/v1/api/js/app/#getversion) show that it exposes the app version to the frontend:

```js
import { getVersion } from '@tauri-apps/api/app';
const appVersion = await getVersion();
```

But how do you get it on the Rust side? Can you use [PackageInfo](https://docs.rs/tauri/1.5.4/tauri/struct.PackageInfo.html#)? It doesn't seem like it implements a method for it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can the the app version from what `App<tauri::Runtime>` exposes:

```rust
    tauri::Builder::default()
        .setup(|app| {
            println!("{}", app.package_info().version.to_string());
            Ok(())
        })
```

You can see a fully working example in my test app [here](https://github.com/tachyonicbytes/so-answers/blob/ce9e0cab17aa269dca48dcc9cd87efc21c2f2522/77524788/tauri-app/src-tauri/src/main.rs#L30).

Comment: It seems you're good with Rust. Would you be interested in contributing your expertise to an open-source cross-platform file manager app? I'm rebuilding my https://github.com/aleksey-hoffman/sigma-file-manager app from scratch on Tauri (Rust + Vue 3). The v2 branch will be published in the next few days, if you'd like to take a look

Comment: Sure, send me a mail. You can find my email in my bio